# es2015 to esnext in Angular 8 project, is it safe?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular8, tsconfig

In Angular 8 project,
if I change in the tsconfig.ts "module" from es2015 to esnext,
is it safe?

The build looks fine but can it cause any problems which I don't see at the moment?